# AngularJs and Fastclick performance issue

Tags: angularjs, performance, events, fastclick.js

I'm working on improving performance of ng application. I've meet with strange side effect of FastClick.

It leads to multiple dispatch Events (see attached image) and to a row of $digest which I would prefer to avoid.

Does anybody know how to cope with such behavior?

[image: timeline of click]

Comment: can u show us the code , so will have better insights on whats happening.

Comment: unfortunetly I can't share the code. when I'll be at home, I'll reproduce it in plunker

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Actually it wasn't "fast click" issue.
It was partially my mistake.
I had a few ng-click handlers that is fired during the event bubbling, and angular-touch ways to $digest on every node element that have ng-click event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it wasn't "fast click" issue.
It was partially my mistake.
I had a few ng-click handlers that is fired during the event bubbling, and angular-touch ways to $digest on every node element that have ng-click event listener.